# Compiled FreeImage from source. #include FreeImage.h not found

Tags: c++, macos, command-line, include

I have compiled FreeImage 3.10.0 from source at **/lib/FreeImage** on Mac OS X 10.6.

I can see that after compilation these files were copied:

```
/usr/local/lib/libfreeimage-3.10.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libfreeimage.a
/usr/local/include/FreeImage.h
```

CMake cannot find FreeImage, but I cannot even do

```
#include <FreeImage.h>  // not found
```

I am assuming I need to add FreeImage.h to the Mac OS X environment path, except I don't know which path is the right one as there are a few different files which store environment path variables.

What do I need to do to get FreeImage header to be found by my C++ app or CMake?

Here is the first part of my `Makefile.osx` is this helps:

```
# -*- Makefile -*-
# Mac OSX makefile for FreeImage

# This file can be generated by ./gensrclist.sh
include Makefile.srcs

# General configuration variables:
CC_PPC = gcc-4.0
CC_I386 = gcc-4.0
CPP_PPC = g++-4.0
CPP_I386 = g++-4.0
COMPILERFLAGS = -Os -fexceptions -fvisibility=hidden
COMPILERFLAGS_PPC = -arch ppc
COMPILERFLAGS_I386 = -arch i386
COMPILERPPFLAGS = -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy
INCLUDE += 
INCLUDE_PPC = -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
INCLUDE_I386 = -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
CFLAGS_PPC = $(COMPILERFLAGS) $(COMPILERFLAGS_PPC) $(INCLUDE) $(INCLUDE_PPC)
CFLAGS_I386 = $(COMPILERFLAGS) $(COMPILERFLAGS_I386) $(INCLUDE) $(INCLUDE_I386)
CPPFLAGS_PPC = $(COMPILERPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_PPC)
CPPFLAGS_I386 = $(COMPILERPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_I386)
LIBRARIES_PPC = -Wl,-syslibroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
LIBRARIES_I386 = -Wl,-syslibroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
LIBTOOL = libtool
LIPO = lipo
```

**Update:** I added these lines into my Makefile as per Nicholas' instructions, then rebuilt but this didn't work:

```
CFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '`INCLUDE +=`' line looks like the one to attack:

```
INCLUDE += -I/usr/local/include
```

If the library is missing too, then you will need to find another line to add '`-L/usr/include/lib`' to.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add -I/usr/local/include to CFLAGS and -L/usr/local/lib to LDFLAGS when compiling.

Comment: Is there meant to be a space between the -I and the path in: `-I/usr/local/include`

Answer (score 0):

Compiling with gcc -c file.c -o file.o -I /usr/local/include should compile your file that refers FreeImage.h.

However, when using isysroot everything becomes relative to the system root (i.e. your refrence to /usr/local/include is in fact *isysroot*/usr/local/include). "gcc -v" will show everything that goes on, making things easy:

```
tmp diciu$ gcc -v -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk test.c
[..]
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/local/include"
```