# #include <FreeImage.h> not found

Tags: c++, macos, osx-snow-leopard, freeimage

I have compiled FreeImage from source and installed it.

When I run `sudo make install` in installs the following files on my system

```
/usr/local/include/FreeImage.h
/usr/local/lib/libfreeimage-3.10.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libfreeimage.a
```

However in my C++ program it says `error file not found` when I do this:

```
#include <FreeImage.h>
```

I have tried adding this to my system path file:

```
sudo vi /etc/paths

#FreeImage
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
```

But C++ still cannot find my `#include` inside Xcode or with gcc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *don't* want those directories in your `/etc/paths` file.  That files lists the directories where the shell searches for executables.

Try:

```
$ CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" make
$ sudo make install
```

You might need to add `/usr/local/lib` to your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to make sure your executable runs:

```
$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

(Assuming your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable doesn't have `/usr/local/lib`, and that it's not empty to begin with.  If it is empty, you should do `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` instead.)

*Edit*: OK, based on your comments, looks like this should work:

```
export CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include
export CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

See [What to do if cmake doesn't find the package although it exists on the system?](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_HowToFindInstalledSoftware#What_to_do_if_cmake_doesn.27t_find_the_package_although_it_exists_on_the_system_.3F) for more.

Since you're using a GUI version of Cmake, you should do this:

Open "property list editor", click "add child".  For "New item", enter `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH`, for Type, leave it as "String", for Value, enter `/usr/local/include`.  Then, click "add item" again, and enter `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` for "New item", leave type as "String", and for  "Value", enter `/usr/local/lib`.  Then save (File -> Save as) to a file.  I suggest filename `a.plist` in your Desktop folder.  Then open a terminal (Appilcations -> Utilities -> Terminal) and type:

```
mv ~/Desktop/a.plist ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
```

After that, quit Xcode and Cmake gui, and restart.  That should work.  See [this](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002093-113982) for technical details, and [this](http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/rowen/AquaEnvVar.html) for more.

Comment: The problem is not that Xcode cannot see the library file, it's that it cannot see the header file. Which file on the system does Xcode consult to see where a `#include <>` exists?

Comment: @Alok thanks for your suggestions. I have added the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS to the makefile and I'm recompiling... fingers crossed.

Comment: It made no difference unfortunately. I think ill try hardcoding the paths for now

Comment: In Xcode, in Project -> Edit Project Settings, in "Build" tab, you can change "Header Search Paths" and "Library Search Paths" in the "Search Paths" option.  Do it for "All Configurations".

Comment: Okay. The problem is that I'm using CMake to build Gazebo, and CMake runs a script internally which uses: `#include <FreeImage.h>` - Is there not some system wide variable which gcc consults?

Comment: If this is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891836/compiled-freeimage-from-source-include-freeimage-h-not-found, try adding the "-I..." to COMPILERFLAGS variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But you say "this should work" where exactly do I use those two commands?

Comment: I am using the GUI version of CMake....CMake builds the Xcode project files for Gazebo.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alok. I've tried the plist file, then restarting and some variations on the things you stated. There's a lot of good things in there, I just think that Apple have made some serious unix changes in 10.6 because it's still not working for me. Anyways I'd double upvote your answer if I could. The tick will have to do. I think this might at least help some other people. Thanks again.

Comment: You could try running commandline version of cmake with the above environment variables set.  I don't use cmake, so I am not sure if the GUI allows you to add include and link paths before running the make process.  I am not sure if the tick helps because you haven't solved your problem and it might prevent others from replying to this question.